# Magento 2: Can you Remove a Block From the Layout Completely

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

In Magento 2, you can *suppress the display of a block* using the `remove` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>
```

However, this doesn't remove the block from the layout completely.  If you tried to insert a new block with the name `product.info.media.image`, you'd get the following error

> main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Element with ID 'product.info.media' already exists.' in /path/to/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:151

Is there a way -- similar to Magento 1's `unsetChild` -- to completely remove a block.

Asking because many Magento 1 extension remove and reinsert blocks, and having a way to do this in Magento 2 would help with automated conversion tools.

Comment: good point, so we are not able anymore, to change a blocks class. It might be intended behavior since it prevents that a template suddenly throws an error because you changed the block to a completely different one. You would still be able to swap it out via di configuration but it would have at least to extend the original block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As near I can tell, you can do do this at the PHP level, but **not** (as of the 2.0/GA release) at an XML level.

The layout structure object (`Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure`), which is the single class that controls which elements are in, or not in, a specific request's layout, has an `unsetChild` and `unsetElement` method.

However, there doesn't appear to be any layout XML directives that allow you to pass through a raw `unsetChild` or `unsetElement` command.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this type of procedure would be seen as redundant in Magento 2 because you can easily move the block using the move layout instruction. Whereas previously this functionality was not implemented in Magento 1.*, so you had to remove the block and then reinsert it, whereas now you can simply move it.

```
 <move element="product.info.media.image" destination="destination"/>
```

**EDIT**: Though, perhaps I'm missing the point of the question completely, as you are Alan Storm, and you certainly probably already know this. Haha!

Comment: +1 for good information -- the specific problem I was trying to solve here was implementing some functionality where a third party module **replaces** named block with its own version by unsetting, then adding with a new name.

Comment: Ah I see. In Magento 2, does it not override it using layout instructions in 'app/code/<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/View/frontend/layout/override'?

Comment: If I could give you another +1 I would for more good information, but that's not quite what I was after either.  The problem with override you're replacing an **entire** layout XML file.  If the file you're replacing includes many blocks using an override increase the likelihood a Magento update will break things.  What I'm looking for is a way to surgically say "remove this single block, replace it with another"

Answer (score 2):

The start of this thread is a little while away, but I want to state, that at least in Magento 2.1.x there is a Method "unsetChild".
It can be called with the following code:

```
  <action method="unsetChild">
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">product.info.addtocart</argument>
    </action>
```